# django arrayfield saving a array item containing comma

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a django model that has a postgres array field
`ArrayField(blank=True, default=list, base_field=CICharField(max_length=200, blank=True))`

There is also a corresponding admin page for this model where I can update field this in the regular case, but If for example I want to save the field as ['foo,bar', 'baz'] this is not possible since django seems to be splitting always by comma. I tried saving with "foo,bar",baz thinking csv rules but that didn't work out either. Is there any workaround to achive this in django admin ?